# legacy camera not detected, bullseye

Tags: camera, operating-systems, libcamera

I have a problem concerning my raspberry pi camera version 2.1. The camera is supported, enabled but is not detected. I'm working with a Raspberry pi 3B+. I'm certain that I have plugged in my camera correctly. Sadly the other posts about this problem didn't really help me. Here is what I have tried out so far.

With sudo raspi-config under interfaces I enabled Legacy Camera. It gave me the following output:

```
Please note that this functionality is deprecated and will not be supported for future development
```

eventhough I'm currently using the earliest version of bullseye. I have also rebooted the raspberry many times in addition to using the commands sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get update.

I get the following output when entering the command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=1 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=1
```

I get the following error when entering this command:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ libcamera-still -o test.jpg
libEGL warning: DRI2: failed to authenticate
Made X/EGL preview window
[0:09:35.012274801] [1547]  INFO Camera camera_manager.cpp:293 libcamera v0.0.1+21-7c855784
ERROR: *** no cameras available ***
```

When entering the following I get: (I have changed this accordingly to the advice from https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1958297

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /boot
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo vi config.txt
[all]
dtoverlay=imx477,media-controller=0
gpu_mem=128
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
start_x=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Raspberry pi 4b 8gb. I reinstalled my os this time using the old Legacy operating system (debian buster) from the raspberry imager. After that camera worked out of the box. I only had to enable it with raspconfig.